# Html 5 Video Plugin for CKEditor 4.1.1

Tags: video, plugins, ckeditor

There was a HTML 5 plugin for ckedior here http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/HTML5-Video

but unfortunately Video plugin doesn't work correctly on CKEditor 4.1.1

It works until you don't see the source, if you click on source and return to editor it write 'Your browser doesn't support video. ...'

Could you please guide me ?

Comment: Where in the config.js does `extraAllowedContent: 'video[*]{*};source[*]{*}'` go? CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) { }

Comment: `config.js` is in root of ckeditor folder. I didn't test `extraAllowedContent`, but `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;` is OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just got the same issue. It seems, that is because, in CKEditor 4.1, they added some Advanced Content Filter. And in fact, if the plugin doesn't say explicitelly that some tag, as `<video></video>` are allowed, they will be just removed by the source editor !!!
My workaround was to disable ACF in the editor, by adding the following line at the begining of the ckeditor/config.js file :

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

By this way, source editor doesn't check anymore for the html content, so it does accept everything !! As a consequence, `<video>...</video>` tag is no more removed !

Hopping it helps

Cheers
-Christian

Comment: thnx Christian your answer helps me lot more.

Comment: This is not simply a work around this is a security breach.

Comment: I can not see browse button. Is there anything else need to be setup?

Answer (score 16):

Instead of turning off the content filtering completely in your ckedito you can just specify

```
extraAllowedContent: 'video[*]{*}'
```

in the config.js file.

Comment: You have to include the "source" tag as well.

`extraAllowedContent: 'video[*]{*};source[*]{*}'`

Comment: To unconfuse: `config.extraAllowedContent = 'video[*]{*};source[*]{*}';`

Comment: This is the only valid answer. The last thing you want is a security breach just because you used `allowedContent = true;`

Answer (score 0):

after downloading plugin extract it in ckeditor/plugin
then go to ckeditor.js file and find "CKEDITOR.config.plugins='"  then add ",video" at the end of it

for Example:
CKEDITOR.config.plugins='dialogui,dialog,about,video';
then plugin work correctly .